# How can I select span in Div using selenium python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to select japan using selenium webdriver in python3.
My code is

```
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#divGlobalContainer > div.icon_flag').click()
```

but it didn't work...I even use xpath..

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='divGlobalContainer']/div[2]/div/ul/li[5]/a").click()
```

but still doesn't work...what's wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try the below XPath expression,

```
".//div[@id='divGlobalContainer']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text())='japan']"
```

Comment: I tried like this...but didn't work.

driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='divGlobalContainer']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text(),'japan')]").click()

Comment: I got this message below.

=======================================================
elenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//div[@id='div1']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text(),'japan')] because of the following error:
Error: Function normalize-space expects at most 1 arguments, 2 given

Comment: sorry i have provided wrong syntax. updated my answer now.Try with the new xpath now.

Comment: thanks...but still didn't work.
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Cannot click on element
===========================================================driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='divGlobalContainer']/descendant::a[normalize-space(text())='japan']").click()

Comment: Is the link displayed under a dropdown?

Comment: without "normalize-space" works too